# firebase, angular(7) and rxjs

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rxjs

when using angular, it is common to use RXjs for promises and I wonder if this is right when using firebase. If so, why (what is the benefit) and how can I do it?

for example, how to wrap the firebase push method, so that the method will return observable and not firebase.database.ThenableReference type

```
 sendMsg(msg: M.ChatMessage) {
    return this.db.list(this.firebaseChatPath).push(msg);
  }
```

Comment: You can turn any Promise (or Promise-like) object into an Observable with `from` method. (`import { from } from 'rxjs';`)

Comment: I'd recommend checking out [AngularFire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2), which wraps the Firebase Realtime Database API in a way that interacts well with Angular. Note btw that `push()` already returns a type that is compatible with `Promise`, so you should be able to pass it anywhere a `Promise` is expected.